# Moq - How to unit test changes on a reference in a method

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, moq

Another day , another question. My service layer has the following method

```
public MatchViewData CreateMatch(string user)
{
    var matchViewData = !HasReachedMaxNumberOfMatchesLimit(user) ?
        CreateMatchAndAddToRepository(user) : 
        MatchViewData.NewInstance(new Match(user));

    matchViewData.LimitReached = HasReachedMaxNumberOfMatchesLimit(user);
    return matchViewData;
}
```

The method calls the this helper method to create a new match object:

```
private MatchViewData CreateMatchAndAddToRepository(string user)
{
    var match = new Match(user);
    MatchRepository.Add(match);
    return MatchViewData.NewInstance(match);
}
```

The repository stores the given match object and sets the id to some value > 0.

```
public void Add(Match match)
{
    Check.Require(match != null);
    var numberOfMatchesBefore = Matches.Count;
    SetIdPerReflection(match, NextVal());
    Matches.Add(match);
    Check.Ensure(numberOfMatchesBefore == Matches.Count - 1);
}
```

The matchviewdata object copies some properties of the the match object (including the id).

My unit test should verify that the resulting viewdata object in the service has an id > 0. To archieve this, i have to mock the repository and the behaviour of the add method. But the service method creates a new match object every time its been called and the add method on the repository updates the referenced match object (there is no need for a return value). I have no idea to solve this with moq.

This is my unit test so far:

```
[Test]
public void ServiceCreateMatchReturnedMatchViewDataHasNonZeroId()
{
    var match = TestUtils.FakePersistentMatch(User, 1);
    var repositoryMock = new Mock<IMatchRepository>();
    repositoryMock.Setup(
           r => r.Add(It.IsAny<Match>())).Callback(() => match.Id = 1);
    var serviceFacade = new DefaultServiceFacade(repositoryMock.Object);

    var returnedMatch = serviceFacade.CreateMatch(User);

    Assert.That(returnedMatch.Id, Is.GreaterThan(0));
}
```

I tried some other variations - nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me your problem is in this line;

```
repositoryMock.Setup(
       r => r.Add(It.IsAny<Match>())).Callback(() => match.Id = 1);
```

What you're actually doing here is setting the id of the first match object you have declared in your test, NOT the new match created in your service.

Because the `Match` object you will be supplying to the Repository is created internally, I can't think of an easy way to reference it in your Test method to setup a callback for it. To me, this is a sign you may be trying to test too much in one unit test.

I think you should simply test that the Add method is called and write a separate test to ensure that it works as exepected.

I propose something like this;

```
[Test]
public void ServiceAddsNewMatchToRepository()
{
   var repositoryMock = new Mock<IMatchRepository>();
   bool addCalled = false;
   repositoryMock
       .Expect(r => r.Add(It.Is<Match>(x => x.Id == 0))
       .Callback(() => addCalled = true);

   var serviceFacade = new DefaultServiceFacade(repositoryMock.Object);
   serviceFacade.CreateMatch(User);

   Assert.True(addCalled);
}

....

[Test]
public void AddingANewMatchGeneratesANewId()
{
  var match = new Match(user);
  var matchRepository = new MatchRepository();
  var returnedMatch = matchRepository.Add(match);

  Assert.That(returnedMatch.Id, Is.GreaterThan(0));      
}
```

Comment: Oh dear. Of cource you are right :-) (and I already had the second test). But sometimes you don't see the wood for the trees... Thanks

Comment: Instead of `.Callback(() => match.Id = 1)` where the argument passed to Moq is **not** used in the call-back, and the `match` modified is a local variable (which is not helpful), @HerrW. can simply use another overload of `Callback` which uses the actual argument. It is as simple as: `.Callback((Match m) => m.Id = 1)`. Of course for more complex stuff a lambda with a body can be used: `.Callback((Match m) => { m.Id = 1; /* more statements can go here */ })`.